# In Seurat, how can I export cluster IDs to csv files

Tags: seurat, single-cell, clustering

I am doing scRNAseq analysis with Seurat.

I clustered the cells using the FindClusters() function.

What I want to do is to export information about which cells belong to which clusters to a CSV file.

In a Seurat object, we can show the cluster IDs by using Idents(・), but I have no idea how to export this to CSV files.

I would be grateful if you could show this by using the PMBC data (https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html) as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clusters information, together with additional information on each cells (%mito, sample name, group, orig.ident,...) are stored inside `seuratObject@meta.data`.
`write.csv(seuratObject@meta.data,"./seurat_metadata.csv")` will dump everything to a file.

The method @osmoc suggested, is using built in seurat functions to interact with `seuratObject@meta.data`.
`seuratObject$graph_name_resolution` points to `seuratObject@meta.data$graph_name_resolution`.

I personally prefer to use the metadata table, as I have more control on how I interact with the data.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Using the `meta.data` slot is the best answer. The behavior of various shortcut methods can change between different versions of Seurat and even based on how you interact with your Seurat object. More generally, it is a bad idea to take columns from different sources when constructing a data frame.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently done this with my own Seurat data; here's the process:

```
# load tidyverse packages
library(tidyverse)
# create cluster ID table
tibble(cellID = colnames(pbmc), clusterID = Idents(pbmc)) %>%
  # write out to a file, with today's date
  write_csv(file = sprintf("cluster_mappings_%s.csv", Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

The clusters are saved in the field `object$seurat_clusters` where `object` represents your Seurat object.

You can also get them running the command `Idents(object)`.

**NOTE**: if you run the command `FindClusters` on different SNN graphs, or different resolutions, you need to specify the clusters by `object$graph_name_resolution`.
Every time you run `FindClusters`, the idents of the cells are updated to the latest results, same for `seurat_clusters`.

For instance, let's say that you have run the command `FindNeighbors` on the `RNA` assay (default value).
Then you run `FindClusters` with `graph = "RNA_snn"` and `resolution=1`.
In that case, the clusters are in `object$RNA_snn_1`.

Once you have the clusters, you can save them as a CSV:

```
clusters <-  <here you use one of the described methods>
# data.frame
clust.df <- data.frame(cellID = colnames(object), clusters = clusters)
write.csv(clust.df, <path.of.the.csv.file>)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !